# how to create transaction without plan in braintree js+python?(whiteout subscription)

Tags: javascript, python, django, payment-gateway, braintree

I am using braintree payment gateway in my application.

i am able to create the transactions with selecting the plan, but what i needed is to create the transaction without selecting any plan. One time payment.

my code

```
create_sub = braintree.Subscription.create({
                            "payment_method_token": the_token,
                            "plan_id": PLAN_ID
                        })
```

here subscription is created.

```
payment_method_result = braintree.PaymentMethod.create({
                        "customer_id": merchant_customer_id,
                        "payment_method_nonce": nonce,
                        "options": {
                            "make_default": True
                        }
                    })
```

here payment_method is got created

here what i want is to create transaction directly without subscribing.
and save all transaction related data to transaction model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You can create a one-time transaction with Braintree's Python API library using the following call:

```
result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
    "amount": "10.00",
    "payment_method_token": the_token,
    "options": {
        "submit_for_settlement": True
    }
})
```

This creates a single transaction with no affiliation to any plan. In place of the "payment_method_token", you may also use "payment_method_nonce", passing in the nonce received from your client. You can find the full list of available parameters in [Braintree's API Documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/python/reference/request/transaction/sale).